# Draw a bowl shaped 3D function hovering over a set

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am wondering if there is any easy way to draw a 3D function defined over a set (its domain). The domain is to be drawn lying "flat" on the ground, and the function is to be drawn "hovering" above the domain. I am thinking of two examples below:

[image]

Note that the function and the domain are convex (if you are familiar with the concept, it means that you can assume the set is "potato-looking" and the function is "bowl shaped").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Here is an example. If you compile with `lualatex` the compilation is faster.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=1+\x*\x+\y*\y;}]
\matrix[column sep=3em]{
\begin{axis}[hide axis,domain=0:1,domain y=0:360,smooth,samples=25,samples y=61]
 \addplot3[surf,shader=flat] ({x*cos(y)},{0.8*x*sin(y)},{0}); 
 \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort] ({x*cos(y)},{0.8*x*sin(y)},{f(x*cos(y),0.8*x*sin(y))});
\end{axis}
&
\begin{axis}[hide axis,domain=0:1,domain y=0:360,smooth,samples=25,samples y=61]
 \addplot3[surf,shader=flat] ({x*cos(y)*(2+sin(3*y))},{0.8*x*sin(y)*(2+sin(3*y)},{0}); 
 \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort] ({x*cos(y)*(2+sin(3*y)},{0.8*x*sin(y)*(2+sin(3*y)},{f(x*cos(y),0.8*x*sin(y))});
\end{axis}\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a triangular domain.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=1+\x*\x+\y*\y;}]
\matrix[column sep=3em]{
\begin{axis}[hide axis,domain=0:1,domain y=0:360,smooth,samples=25,samples y=61,
    declare function={myx(\x,\y)=\x*cos(\y);myy(\x,\y)=\x*sin(\y);}]
 \addplot3[surf,shader=flat] ({myx(x,y)},{myy(x,y)},{0}); 
 \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort] 
    ({myx(x,y)},{myy(x,y)},{f(myx(x,y),myy(x,y))});
\end{axis}
&
\begin{axis}[hide axis,domain=-1:1,domain y=0:1,samples=25,samples y=61,
 declare function={myx(\x,\y)=\x;myy(\x,\y)=\y*(1-abs(\x));}]
 \addplot3[surf,shader=flat] ({myx(x,y)},{myy(x,y)},{0}); 
 \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,z buffer=sort] 
    ({myx(x,y)},{myy(x,y)},{f(myx(x,y),myy(x,y))});
\end{axis}\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that you can also use filters, but then the boundaries look a bit pixelated in general.

Comment: `samples=25,samples y=61`, odd numbers, gotcha!

Comment: @manooooh This means that the number of intervals is even, and the shape looks more symmetric. Otherwise I'd choose perfect numbers. ;-)

Comment: Well, in 9 minutes it's my `21` birthday so I think I'm more symmetric than just yesterday!

Comment: @manooooh Happy Birthday!

Comment: This is wonderful! But if you see my right drawing, what if the "domain" is not a parametric function the way you use, but  instead something like a triangle? Can something similar be done then?

Comment: @space_voyager Yes, of course. I added an example.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!